# Using SVG filters in CSS for IE10

Tags: css, image, internet-explorer-10, svg-filters

IE10 has dropped support for its DirectX image manipulations; it now uses the SVG standards. However, in Firefox, for example, you can apply an svg filter to any `<img>` element but in IE10, and I can only seem to get it to work on images in `<svg> <image ... /> </svg>`.

Do I need to write separate markup for different browsers? That seems wrong.

I tried using the CSS filters like `-ms-filter` filter but none of those worked on IE10.

UPDATE 1:

Okay so I guess I may not have been particularly clear.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>
    .pop {

        filter: url(#pixelate);

    }

    .pop:hover {
        filter: none;
    }

    .lol {
        filter: url(#pixelate);
    }

    .lol:hover {
        filter: none;
    }

    .svgRoot
{
    height: 150px;
    width: 200px;
}
</style>
<svg class="svgRoot">
<image class="lol" x="0" y="0" width="100px" height="100px"  xlink:href="http://i.imgur.com/M5TIb.jpg" />
</svg>

<svg class="svgRoot">
    <defs>
        <filter id="pixelate">
            <feMorphology operator="erode" radius="2" />
        </filter>
    </defs>
    <image x="0" y="0" width="100px" height="100px" xlink:href="http://i.imgur.com/M5TIb.jpg" filter="url(#pixelate)" />
    <text class="svgText" x="25%" y="90%" filter="url(#pixelate)">SVG text</text>
</svg>

<img src="http://i.imgur.com/M5TIb.jpg" width="100" class="pop">
```

In Firefox, the last element, the `<img>`, the filter works. However, it doesn't in IE10. I could achieve the same affect here using IE4-IE9 with DX. effects. But IE10 implements SVG. However it only seems to work on elements contained within the `<svg>` tag. So how am I to do any filter effects in IE10 without writing different markup? I feel like I must be missing something...

Hope this clears it up

Comment: I don't think Firefox supports `filter` in CSS. Can you add a code sample to your question?

Comment: Updated with some code, horrible code, but some code :)

Comment: This [partially works](http://jsfiddle.net/aSUSr/1/) in Chrome (`<text>` is invisible), other browser have various problems displaying it. I usually use option 2 (define filters inside each `<svg>` element), but I can't get it working this time.

Comment: Yeah what I ended up doing was having two implementations, one with <img> and normal CSS filters (for chrome and ie 9 and below), and another with <svg><image...></svg> with the filter inside; displaying the different implementations based on the users browser. Messy... ^^

Comment: have you managed to apply filters to images outside svg tags? This truly sucks :(. Only IE10 giving this issue!

Comment: Sorry I had to use <svg> tags for IE10 :(

Answer (score 1):

If you need a specific style in IE10+, it'll pickup in CSS using:

```
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) { styles here }
```

Comment: The problem is more that the specific style I want to apply to an element only works if it is an SVG element and that pretty much sucks

Comment: @Hazza I'm running into the same issue. I haven't found a satisfying or correct answer yet except to use SVG. Which sucks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this inside a company, you can petition your sys admins to [configure IE10's group policy to accept the old-style filter syntax](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj891001.aspx). If you are doing this on the open internet, then you are SOL. The new stuff only works on svg elements and the old stuff has been removed.